# Crumbling Wall Near Fireplace

Tags: walls, repair, fireplace, plaster

My house has a gas fireplace with Spanish tile and what I can only assume is plaster to create a textured wall. A few months ago, it started crumbling and would fall to the ground with significant dust and chunks of what I think is plaster. There was no impact that I am aware of although I do have a 3 and a 4 year old so it’s always a possibility that something hit it unknowingly. Since then it’s been getting bigger. We were gone for a weekend and came home to even more pieces of the wall and dust on the ground. I am hoping for two things: most importantly, how can I fix it? Secondly, could there be a cause signaling a larger issue?
I rent and have lived in this house for about 5 years. I don’t know the logistics of the build. Our property management company isn’t much help and threatened a large fee if they had to come repair it.
This is the first time this has happened and the house is in otherwise great condition.
I don’t know much about these kinds of repairs or structures in general. I’m good for a machine repair but I’m truly clueless here. My internet research has not yielded any useful results so far.
Any tips/help is appreciated[image]